# Understand cookie context

Tags: windows, cookies

I want to understand the cookie file in my Windows 7 desktop. Please see the file

```
PREF
ID=3e18279f8c2c19f0:U=bdb674f5343dd419:FF=0:LD=en:TM=1351188541:LM=1351780095:GM=1:S=ujBw6xOn15AcAVx6
google.com/
1536
311486848
30406112
557488263
30259261
*
NID
65=AQ-mQmM4_j64Pb3M5S6Mrpw7xQngOCk5UacjLp5OtuwSUeuoEkbDSSlRjT_Ozi-HuP7vbKTGov07i6Ge1eIEA_TaTCUEZG3ehQZ1FQhvRD3Dbelo-2kRvlu_4QtwjIdhLtRdMbEPzpDj
google.com/
9216
3854504704
30296126
2487404940
30259313
*
```

The file is located at

> c:\users\account name\appdata\roaming\microsoft\windows\cookies\low

There is only one file for the timebeing. I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Google has page witch explains use of every type of Cookie they use. According to this, Cookie you are looking at contains information about your preferences and about targeted adverts.

Take a look here:

http://www.google.com/policies/technologies/types/

> **Preferences**
>
> These cookies allow our websites to remember information that changes
>   the way the site behaves or looks, such as your preferred language or
>   the region you are in. For instance, by remembering your region, a
>   website may be able to provide you with local weather reports or
>   traffic news. These cookies can also assist you in changing text size,
>   font and other parts of web pages that you can personalize.
>
> Loss of the information stored in a preference cookie may make the
>   website experience less functional but should not prevent it from
>   working.
>
> Most Google users will have a preferences cookie called ‘PREF’ in
>   their browsers. A browser sends this cookie with requests to Google’s
>   sites. The PREF cookie may store your preferences and other
>   information, in particular your preferred language (e.g. English), how
>   many search results you wish to have shown per page (e.g. 10 or 20),
>   and whether or not you wish to have Google’s SafeSearch filter turned
>   on.
>
> **Advertising**
>
> We use cookies to make advertising more engaging to users and more
>   valuable to publishers and advertisers. Some common applications of
>   cookies are to select advertising based on what’s relevant to a user;
>   to improve reporting on campaign performance; and to avoid showing ads
>   the user has already seen.
>
> Google uses cookies, like the PREF cookie, to help personalize ads on
>   Google properties, like Google Search, particularly when you aren’t
>   signed in to a Google account. We also use cookies for advertising we
>   serve outside of Google. Our main advertising cookie on non-Google
>   sites is called ‘id’ and it is stored in browsers under the domain
>   doubleclick.net. We use others with names such as *drt*, FLC, NID and
>   exchange_uid.
>
> Sometimes a cookie may be set on the domain of the site you are
>   visiting. In the case of our DoubleClick product, a cookie called
>   ‘__gads’ may be set on the domain of the site you are visiting.
>
> Other Google properties, like YouTube, may also use the DoubleClick
>   cookie to personalize ads. Find out more about ads and YouTube.
>
> Google also uses various conversion cookies to help advertisers
>   determine how many times people who click on their ads end up
>   purchasing their products. These cookies allow Google and the
>   advertiser to tell that you clicked the ad and later visited the
>   advertiser site. Conversion cookies are not used by Google for
>   interest based ad targeting and persist for a limited time only. These
>   cookies are generally set in the googleadservices.com domain, but may
>   also be set in the google.com/ads domain. Conversion cookie data may
>   also be used in combination with your Google account to link
>   conversion events across different devices you use. Only anonymous
>   conversion cookie data is shared with advertisers.
>
> Some of our advertising products allow other companies to send their
>   own cookies to your browser. For example, when you visit a page that
>   uses DoubleClick, you may find that cookies are sent to your browser
>   by Google and also by other parties. Each publisher and advertiser may
>   work with various technology and service providers and each of these
>   parties may set its own cookies, though each cookie can only be read
>   by the domain that sets it. This means that several cookies may be
>   sent to your browser by several companies in the time it takes a
>   single web page to load. This is how most online advertising works.